# Polymorphism and instanceof confusion

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, instanceof

I am confused how an object is an `instanceof` two different classes. For example:

```
EnglishTest x = new EnglishQuiz();
if (x instanceof EnglishTest){
   System.out.print("P");
}
if (x instanceof EnglishQuiz){
   System.out.print("P");
}
```

In both cases I get "P" printed out. My question is why?

I understand that `x` is of type `EnglishTest` but since I am doing `new EnglishQuiz` shouldn't that mean I am creating an instance of `EnglishQuiz` and not `EnglishTest` as well? What is going on here?

Comment: Is `EnglishQuiz` a kind of `EnglishTest`?

Comment: Yes `EnglishQuiz extends EnglishTest` sorry for not adding that.

Comment: It's kind of like biology. Humans are Mammals, as well as Giraffes. Each Human is an instance of the class Human, as well as Mammal. Each Giraffe would be an instance of Giraffe, and as well as Mammal. But a Giraffe wouldn't be an instance of Human and vice versa. Mammal in this case would be the superclass of Human and Giraffe, and they would share some common properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Test {
     //implicitly inherits type Object
}

class Quiz extends Test {
     //explicitly inherits type Test
     //implicitly inherits type Object
}

class PopQuiz extends Quiz {
     //explicitly inheirts type Quiz
     //implicitly inheirts type Test and Object
}
```

`Object -> Test -> Quiz -> PopQuiz`

`instanceof` refers to the type of the instance. If an instance implicitly or explicitly "extends" a class, it is an instanceof that type, since it inherits the type of the class its extending (and any other classes that are extended upon, as seen in my hierarchy example).

PopQuiz is both a Quiz AND a Test. Therefore, an instance of PopQuiz inherits both types Quiz amd Test, so it is an instanceof Quiz AND Test.

Comment: Ohh I guess I am thinking something that's untrue about the `instaceof` key word.

Comment: @SimionMita You could post what you believe it does, and ask if its true or not

Comment: Well based on what you both mentioned `instanceof` checks if a class is an instance of a class but as I just learned it also checks, and returns true, if you're checking with the subclass of the given class such as my `EnglishQuiz`.

Comment: @SimionMita Do you mean "checks if an object is an instance of a certain class"? Because keep in mind, when you extend, you're taking whats there and adding onto it, meaning the subclass is still considered to be what the superclass is, just a more complex version. `class Poodle extends Dog { }` Poodle is a Dog, its just a more complex version. Thats why this is possble: `Dog poodle = new Poodle()`. Doing this means "if the subclass overrode methods, use the code thats in Poodle. other than that, ignore any methods in Poodle that arent in Dog (methods that werent inherited from Dog)

Comment: Yes I understand that a subclass keeps adding onto the superclass's contents :). Basically what I meant is that the `instanceof` also works for subclasses. So `Poodle` would be an `instaceof` `Dog`. Right?

Comment: @SimionMita Thats correct. Just keep in mind, when you're doing `(item instanceof Class)`, `Class` is referring to the Type, not the stand-alone class

Answer (score 5):

If this line compiles:

```
EnglishTest x = new EnglishQuiz();
```

Then there must be an `is-a` relationship between `EnglishTest` and `EnglishQuiz`; specifically, an `EnglishQuiz` must be a subtype of an `EnglishTest`, much like how an `Integer` is a `Number`.

Thus, `x instanceof EnglishTest` is true, in the same way `Integer instanceof Number` is true. An `EnglishQuiz` is an `EnglishTest`, after all.

Looking at the Java Language Specification [Section 15.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> At run time, the result of the instanceof operator is true if the value of the RelationalExpression is not null and the reference could be cast (§15.16) to the ReferenceType without raising a ClassCastException. Otherwise the result is false.

Because an `EnglishQuiz` could always be cast to an `EnglishTest` (such a cast is called an upcast and is always allowed, because an object can always be classified as its supertype), the `instanceof` operator returns `true`.

Another way of visualizing this might be this:

```
          Object
             |
          Number
           /  \
      Integer  Float
      /     \
     Pos.  Neg.
    /  \   /  \
   1    2 -4  -5
```

`x instanceof y` will return true if `y` is either the same type as `x` or if you can reach `y` by going up from `x`.

Comment: I understand but my confusion comes as I always remember that an object instance is created with `new` at least that's what my teacher told me. Yet now there is apparently two instances even though only `EnglishQuiz` has been initialized. Based on what you said and according to the is-a relationship is it truly safe and accurate to say that x is an instance of both EnglishQuiz and EnglishTest?

Comment: There isn't two instances; the only instance there is is the one you created using the `new` keyword. There is a distinction between a *type* and an *instance*; an instance is simply an object created from a class, whereas a type is a piece of data that goes along with the object and describes where it sits in Java's type hierarchy.

Comment: @SimonMita `instanceof` refers to the type. It will return true if that instance inheits the type aswell. All classes are instanceof Object. Check my answer

Comment: And you are correct in saying that `x` is an instance of both `EnglishQuiz` and `EnglishTest`. It's like saying `1 is-a WholeNumber is-a Integer is-a- Number is-a- Object`. You have only one `1`, but it is an instance of all those types.